# Why does using loop-only functions in a def section not work, even when in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a small text-based game in Python. It involves many inputs and so to avoid bugs, there are a few things I have to check every time an input exists. Naturally, to speed up the process I wanted to put the code into a def in order to simplify the writing process. When I put the code in the def, it red underlines the continue and break commands (meaning they are incorrect), and if you run the code using the def name, a Traceback occurs. I have tried putting the def section at the beginning of the program, after the `while True:` (The program is supposed to run infinitely until a certain action is taken that breaks the loop) I have also made sure to try putting it under any variables referenced and in the loop so that no part of it is not defined and so that everything would work if I were to just put the code in there.

Here is the code I am trying to put into a def.

```
def input_bugs():
    if letter_one.lower() == "done" and total_count == 0:
        print("You have to play at least one game!")
        continue
    elif letter_one.lower() == "done":
        break
    elif len(letter_one) > 1:
        print("Sorry, you gotta pick a single letter, no more. Otherwise, type 'done' to end the game and see your stats.")
        continue
```

Here is the Traceback I get every time I try to run it.

```
 line 20
    continue
    ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
```

At this point, I don't even care if I have to write it out every time, I can just copy and paste. I am simply curious as to why it doesn't work so that I know in the future. In case you could not tell, I am pretty new to programming so I want to learn from any mistake I make. Also sorry if I referred to some things in the wrong way. Hopefully, you understood what I meant.

Comment: `continue` brings you back to the top of a loop, but you have no loop in the function. Did you intend a `return`?

Comment: `continue` and `break` only apply to loops.  If you want to exit a function, you use `return`.  If you need to different results, then `return 0` and `return 1`, and do `if input_bugs():` in the main code.

Comment: Perhaps the best thing is to have the function return True or False and then the thing that does the call does the continue. Its a bit risky to write an answer because I'm guessing about the code. Is there a very simple example you could post?

Comment: OP please correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the confusion is that you called this function from within a loop and are expecting `continue` to act on the loop block which called the function? If that is the case, be aware that `continue` and `break` do not work in this way. Once you call into a function you lose the context of the loop. What you want is more like a macro which doesn't exist in standard Python code.